# Changing the colour of a result in a subtraction sum

Tags: color, stringstrings

[image]

I am trying to produce something like this pic, were the crossed out parts in the answer could be coloured white or not shown, to try and show the steps involved in the subtraction method.

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{dvipsnames}{xcolor}
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xlop}
\usepackage{pstricks}

\newcommand{\myRed}[1]{\textcolor{red}{#1}}

%-------numberline code----------
% arrows.meta for the uptodate arrow tips
% shapes.misc for the cross out shape
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, shapes.misc, bending}
\newcommand*\tikznumberlineset{\pgfqkeys{/tikz/number line}}
\tikznumberlineset{
  arrow/.style={/tikz/>={#1}},
  start/.initial=1, end/.initial=5,
  tick length/.initial=2pt, overhang/.initial=.75,
  %
  % Nodes
   start-end dot/.style={% those are the dots
   shape=circle, fill=black, minimum size=+4pt,
    inner sep=+0pt, outer sep=+0pt, node contents=},
   %% defaults for "start dot" and "end dot"
  start dot/.style=number line/start-end dot,
  end dot/.style  =number line/start-end dot,
  %% number below the ticks
  value node/.style={
    below=2pt, font=\footnotesize, node contents=$\tikznumberlinevalue$},
  %% text above diagram
  instruction node/.style={
     anchor=south, yshift=5pt, font=\small, node contents=%
      Move \nlvo{units text} to the \emph{\nlvo{direction text}}.},
  %
  % 'Start' and 'End' node, "start-end label"
  % can be used for additional labels
  start-end label/.style={font=\small,yshift=-.75cm},
  start label/.style={number line/start-end label,
     text=Cerulean,node contents=Start},
   end label/.style  ={number line/start-end label,
     text=OrangeRed,node contents=End},
  %
  % Lines, can be used to change color, thickness, etc.
  line/.style ={draw,<->},
  ticks/.style=draw,
  connection/.style={draw=MidnightBlue,out=45,in=135},
  %
  % direction=left or direction=right
  %% the direction changes
  %%  * the arrow tip
  %%  * the text left/right in the instruction and
  %%  * where "Start" and "End" will be set.
  direction text/.initial=, units text/.initial=,
  direction/.is choice,
  direction/left/.style={
     connection/.append style=<-, direction text=left,
     label left/.style =number line/end label,
     label right/.style=number line/start label},
  direction/right/.style={
    connection/.append style=->, direction text=right,
    label left/.style =number line/start label,
    label right/.style=number line/end label},
  direction=right,% default
  %
  % to doesn't like foreach, going to use .list
  % which uses foreach internally
  @toloop/.style={
     /utils/exec=\def\tikznumberlinevalue{#1},% make #1 available
    insert path={to[number line/edge/.try,number line/edge #1/.try] (#1,0)}},
   add edge node/.style args={#1[#2]#3}{edge #1/.append style={
     edge node={node
       [number line/edge node/.try,number line/edge node #1/.try,#2]{#3}}}},
  add edge label/.style args={#1[#2]#3}{
    add edge node={#1[number line/start-end label,at end,#2]#3}},
  add edge dot/.style args={#1[#2]}{
    add edge node={#1[number line/start-end dot,behind path,at end,#2]}},
  all dots/.style={edge/.append style={
    edge node={node[number line/start-end dot,at end,#1]{}}}},
  all dots/.default=}
\newcommand*\tikznumberline[1][]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \tikznumberlineset{#1}
   \newcommand*\nlvo[1]{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/number line/##1}}
   \pgfmathint{\nlvo{end}-(\nlvo{start})}
   \pgfkeyssetevalue{/tikz/number line/units text}{\pgfmathresult}
  %
  % 1. The lines and the ticks:
   \path[number line/ticks] (\nlvo{start}-1-\nlvo{overhang},\nlvo{tick length})
             grid[ystep=0] (\nlvo{end}+1+\nlvo{overhang},-\nlvo{tick length});
   \path[number line/line] (\nlvo{start}-1-\nlvo{overhang},0)
                        -- (\nlvo{end}+1+\nlvo{overhang},0);
   %
   % 2. the black circles (these are nodes now)
   %    and the labels "Start" and "End"
   \path (\nlvo{start},0) node (@number line@start) [number line/start dot]
                         node [number line/label left]
         (\nlvo{end},0)   node (@number line@end)   [number line/end dot]
                     node [number line/label right];
  %
  % 3. the numbers below the ticks
   \foreach \tikznumberlinevalue[expand list]
     in {\the\numexpr\nlvo{start}-1\relax,...,\the\numexpr\nlvo{end}+1\relax}
       \node at (\tikznumberlinevalue,0) [number line/value node];
  %
  % 4. the hopping line which is fully connected, no movetos anymore
  %    the last edge is available via the last edge key if one needs to add
  \path[number line/connection](@number line@start)
    [number line/@toloop/.list/.expanded={%
      \the\numexpr\nlvo{start}+1\relax,...,\the\numexpr\nlvo{end}-1\relax}]
     to[number line/last edge/.try] (@number line@end);
  % 5.
   \node at ({(\nlvo{start}+\nlvo{end})/2},\nlvo{tick length})
    [number line/instruction node];
\end{tikzpicture}}

 \tikznumberlineset{arrow=Stealth}
\tikzset{small cross out/.style={
  cross out,at end,minimum size=2mm,draw=gray,ultra thick,line cap=round}}

%-------End numberline code-----------

%-------Start Subtraction Code----------%
\usepackage{stringstrings,stackengine}

\usepackage{xcolor}% 
\colorlet{digits}{black}
\colorlet{cross}{teal}
\colorlet{upper}{blue}
\colorlet{answer}{red}
\colorlet{borrow}{blue}  

\newcommand\showdiff[2]{%
    \let\savediff\relax%
    \def\borrow{}%
    \xdef\borrowed{0}%
    \ifnum#1>32\relax\showdiffengine{#1}{#2}\else
    {\ttfamily\Longstack[r]{#1\,{} \underline{-#2\,} {< 0\,}}}\fi
}
\newcommand\showdiffengine[2]{%
     \xdef\opA{#1}%
     \xdef\opB{#2}%
     \lastdigits{\opA}{\opB}%
     \ifnum\borrowed=1\relax\xdef\XdigA{\the\numexpr\digA-  1}\else\xdef\XdigA{\digA}\fi%
     \ifnum\XdigA<0\relax\xdef\XdigA{9}\xdef\futureborrowed{1}\else
     \xdef\futureborrowed{0}\fi
     \edef\coldiff{\the\numexpr\XdigA-\digB\relax}%
     \ifnum\coldiff<0\relax%
     \xdef\borrow{1}%
     \edef\coldiff{\the\numexpr\borrow\XdigA-\digB\relax}%
     \else
    \xdef\borrow{}%
    \fi
    \ifnum\borrowed=0\relax%
    \savestack{\thediff}{%
        \ttfamily\Longstack[l]{%
            \tiny\bllap[1.5\baselineskip]{\textcolor{borrow}{\borrow}}    \textcolor{digits}{\XdigA{}} \underline{\textcolor{digits}{\VdigB}\kern3pt} % 
            \textcolor{answer}{\coldiff}}}% 
    \else
    \savestack{\thediff}{\ttfamily\Longstack[l]{%
            \tiny\brlap[.7\baselineskip]{\color{upper}\borrow\the\numexpr\XdigA}   \crossout{\textcolor{digits}{\digA}} % % 
             \underline{\textcolor{digits}{\VdigB}\kern3pt}%
             \\ \textcolor{answer}{\coldiff}}}% 
    \fi
    \if\relax\borrow\relax\xdef\borrowed{0}\else\xdef\borrowed{1}\fi
     \savestack{\savediff}{\thediff\savediff}%
     \ifnum\futureborrowed>0\relax\xdef\borrowed{1}\xdef\fugureborrowed{0}\fi
    \nextcolumn{\opA}{\opB}%
    \ifnum\numexpr0\opA+0\opB>0\relax\showdiffengine{\opA}{\opB}%
    \else
    \Longstack{\underline{\ttfamily-\,} {}}\savediff\fi%
 }
 \newcommand\crossout[1]{\stackengine{0pt}{#1}{\textcolor{cross}{/}}{O}{c}{F}{F} {L}}% 
\newcommand\lastdigits[2]{%
    \substring[q]{#1}{$}{$}%
    \xdef\digA{\thestring}%
    \xdef\VdigA{\digA}\if0\digA\ifnum#1=0\relax\xdef\VdigA{~}\fi\fi%
    \substring[q]{#2}{$}{$}%
    \xdef\digB{\thestring}%
    \xdef\VdigB{\digB}\if0\digB\ifnum#2=0\relax\xdef\VdigB{~}\fi\fi%
}
 \newcommand\nextcolumn[2]{%
    \substring[q]{#1}{1}{$-1}%
    \xdef\opA{0\thestring}%
    \substring[q]{#2}{1}{$-1}%
     \xdef\opB{0\thestring}%
     %-------------End Subtraction Code------------------%
}

\begin{document}

\opadd[carryadd=false, resultstyle=\white]{135}{49}\\   
            
    \showdiff{135}{9}\bigskip       

    \tikznumberline[start=6, end= 15, direction=left,
  add edge label={0[green]Middle},
  add edge node={14[fill=white,font=\tiny\sffamily]-6},
  add edge dot={0[green]}
]   
            
    \showdiff{135}{49}\bigskip  
            
    \tikznumberline[start=8, end= 12, direction=left,
  add edge label={0[green]Middle},
  add edge node={11[fill=white,font=\tiny\sffamily]-4},
  add edge dot={0[green]}
]

    \showdiff{135}{49}\bigskip  


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is a manual fix. You'll have to make adjustments for each use. Change `\hspace{-9mm}` to move the box left or right; change `\rule{6mm}` to adjust the width of the box. `2ex` is the height, `-1pt` drops the box below the baseline to make sure it completely covers the characters.

[image]

```
\showdiff{135}{9}\hspace{-9mm}\raisebox{-1pt}[0pt][0pt]{\textcolor{white}{\rule{6mm}{2ex}}}\bigskip
```

I changed `white` to `blue` just so you can see the rectangle covering the numbers.

[image]